Create a modular npm package
I am making some kind like query, and able to make it to be able to use any modules, like mysql, mssql, etc to support my work, and if possible, share it to npm library.
Currently, I have to install all of them, and I end up with a bunch of mysql2, mssql, tedious, and pgsql. They are taking lots of unnecessary resources.
But despite I've installed easy-query-mysql for example, at my app along with easy-query, easy-query still couldn't import it. Perhaps there is some isolation on nodejs side.
I've tried to make it to try to import like easy-query-mysql, and skip the adapter if it is not found. So it is like this:
app
|- node_modules
|  |- easy-query
|  |  |- index.js
|  |- easy-query-mysql
|- index.js

/app/index.js
const query = await EasyQuery.connect('mysql://user:pass@localhost/database');

/app/node_modules/easy-query/index.js
const adapter = await import('easy-query-mysql`)

That yield ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND at import('easy-query-mysql')
I am wondering, if I can let the user to install only the module they need? For example, let's say my package is easy-query, but it comes with no modules. And then if the user add easy-query\mysql to their project for example, with something like npm i easy-query easy-query\mysql and then the easy-query would be able to accept connection like mysql://dbuser:passwd@localhost/database. And if the user add easy-query\mssql, then the user would be able to connect to mssql://dbuser:passwd@localhost/database, and so on
If it is possible, how to structure my projects to be able do such thing? Is there any resources that I can read on how to do that?

You'll can add the extra packages in peerDependencies in package.json, and in peerDependenciesMeta section add them as optional so it won't install them automatically.
"peerDependencies": { 
"easy-query-mysql": ">= 1.0.0"
},
"peerDependenciesMeta": {
  "easy-query-mysql": {
    "optional": true
  }
}

You can also use a file path if you want to link to local package
"peerDependencies": { 
"easy-query-mysql": "file://project/easy-query-mysql"
},
"peerDependenciesMeta": {
  "easy-query-mysql": {
    "optional": true
  }
}

Just make sure to add --preserve-symlinks to node
node --preserve-symlinks index.js

You are not in control of which version will be install so don't specify exact version but use logical operation base on your support.
Inside your code you'll need to have handling for the different optional cases.
let easy-query-mysql;
try {
  easy-query-mysql = await import('easy-query-mysql');
} catch (er) {
  easy-query-mysql = null;
}

if (easy-query-mysql) {
  // Whatever you want 
}

If needed you can use semver to check package version.

Thank you.. That does it. I want to add a note though, that if you want to use local peerDependencies from file:// you need to add parameter --preserve-symlinks to node.exe. Spent some time figuring it out before it worked

You can edit my response, I'll approve
